# Abstract class as foreign key

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, django-models

Im trying to create relationship between class Locomotion and Section. Every Section has to have a king of Locomotion chosen (Class Locomotion is extended by Plain/Bus/Train etc.). And i'm getting the error about "Field defines a relation with model 'Locomotion', which is either not installed, or is abstract.". There is any way to do it? From what i read till now, there is no good way to do it, or i am mistaken?

My class Section:

```
class Section(RoadElements):
    locomotion = models.ForeignKey(Locomotion, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Section, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

which extends class RoadElements, abstract as well.

My definition of Locomotion:

```
class Locomotion(models.Model):
    transportation_firm_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    transportation_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    departure_date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    arrival_date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    reservation = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

And class extending, for example :

```
class Plain(Locomotion):
    seat_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    class_section = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: **Locomotion** is defined in the same app or same models.py?

Comment: Locomotion is defined in the same models.py.

Comment: Please try `locomotion = models.ForeignKey("Locomotion", on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Comment: @trantu I was trying this before, i get the error " Field defines a relation with model 'Locomotion', which is either not installed, or is abstract."

Comment: Did you declare **Locomotion** as abstract class like `class Locomotion(...): class Meta: abstract = True`?

Comment: @trantu Yes. I add declaration in body of question for better insight.

Comment: You can not reference to an abstract class because it does not create a database table 


  https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Comment: @trantu I know that very well, so it's a reason of my question, for anyway to do it. I would prefer to stay with abstract class and avoiding of redundant columns in three or more tables.

Comment: So you can use **GenericForeignKey** instead to reference to an exended class from **Locomotion**: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have a foreign key to an abstract base class, because there is no database table for that class.  In your example: there will be a database table with rows for `Plain` instances, but no table for `Locomotion`.

The usual way to do this is using a [Generic Foreign Key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) to point to one of the child classes.

Comment: I don't know if i understand this well, but i found on stack overflow that using Generic Foreign Key is no longer valid. Am i mistaken?